# My Button for the opening page won't work. Using Xamarin (C#, XAML) and restructuring the project into MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have just restructured my Xamarin project into MVVM using the tutorial by Eduardo Rosas about Xamarin. I can't get the "Begin" button to work on the first page thats launched by the Android emulator. It looks right, according to what Eduardo did. Here is the XAML for the "Landing Page" (first page loaded by the App).

**XAML for opening page (Landing Page)**

[image: XAML for opening page (Landing Page)]

Here is the code for the code behind of the Landing Page (first page on app):

**Code Behind**

[image]

Here is the view model for the landing page:

**VIEW MODEL FOR LANDING PAGE**

[image]

Here is the ICommand for PickFromThreePageCommand.cs calling the Begin_Button_tapped:

**ICommand**

[image]

The PickFromThreePage has three buttons and is the page the Begin_Button_Tapped navigates too. When I run the app on my Android emulator, the LandingPage comes up and I click the "Begin" Button and it shows distortion like it knows it's being tapped but doesn't navigate to the next page...PickFromThreePage. Below is a pick of the emulator:

[image]

Here is a pick of the PickFromThreePageVM just for good measure:

[image]

EDIT:
My Begin_Button_Taped() didn't have "async" and "await" for the navigation. It still doesn't work but I thought I would add this in.

Comment: please DO NOT post code and errors as images

Comment: hint: your button's command is bound to a property that doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry about that, I won't post anymore code and errors as images. I will also check the properties.

Comment: You are right. Here's the error:

Comment: Binding: 'BeginButtonCommand' property not found on 'Flora.ViewModel.LandingPageVM', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Button.Command'

Comment: XAML Button Command calls BeginButtonCommand. BeginButtonCommand executes Begin_BUTTON_TAPPED(). It's also declared in my viewmodel. Eduardo did the same exact thing I did and his project works. This is driving me crazy!!! I've been stuck on this for two days now (about 15 hours!).

Comment: Eduardo Rosas's project is on GitHub and it's called TravelRecordApp and it's a Xamarin project.

Comment: "go look on Github" is just as bad as posting images.  Not trying to be mean, but you'll get better responses if you follow the site rules.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's begin. So your code behind and XAML are fine, coming to your View Model I believe you are making it too complex for no reason. Your button ICommand should look something like this (all this should be in your VM):

```
  Public ICommand PickFromThreePageCommand {get; set;}
```

Then in your Constructor your initialize it:

```
   public LandingPageVM
  {
      PickFromThreePageCommand= new Command(PickFromThreePage)
  }
```

And then define the method something like this:

```
    private void PickFromThreePage(object obj)
   {
              // Click event code
   }
```

Comment: You just saved me a ton of time. I don't know how to thank you! Thanks for just giving me the code and not telling me to read Data Bindings again with some link on the basics. Like I haven't done that a million times already(???). I will green check mark your solution as well...and no more images of code too.

Comment: Its my pleasure to help, and its okay if you read something and don't understand when your new, trust me been there and done that! Anyways goodluck if in case you want to learn xamarin further you can follow me on medium ?and checkout my blogs! Link in my Bio, Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, I got on medium and marked you as following. I will check out your stuff.